# 32F429IDISCOVERY board hard fault/default handler

Tags: c, ocr, stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32ldiscovery

I'm trying to implement a GOCR algorithm to 32F429IDISCOVERY board. The GOCR itself works very well on PC but on the discovery board I'm still having some issues that makes it unstable and unusable. Sometimes the algorithm works fine, everything goes well and the result is great but sometimes the processor gets stuck in hard fault/default handler. I cannot tell what is the reason of the crash and what am I supposed to do but I believe that stack/heap got overflowed.
Below I attached an image that shows the state of the processor before and after the crash:

[image]

Comment: we cannot debug your code without the actual code

Comment: yeah but to code is quite complex and i dont relly understand it...It looks like a general problem that why I attached a CPU registers in the image...

If the crash was happening only in one place I would post the code but it's happening on numerous places...

Comment: If you suspect a stack overflow, the debugger is telling you the stack pointer, so you can follow that up. Also many systems preset the stack memory with a pretty pattern just so you can examine it with a debugger and see how much you are using.

Comment: I think its more like heap overflow because I'm processing a lot of data, stack is bacically empty...